# Can Suggested Edit Reviews show the close reason in more detail?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

At the moment when reviewing a suggested edit on a closed post the close reason shown in the queue is very vague, with no way to get more information other than to open the question in a new tab.

This screenshot shows the problem: This question was closed as needing debugging details but I could not tell from the reason here ("This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow Guideline" also does seem repetitive to me as that would be the only reason why a question would be closed in the first place?)
[image: Suggested Edit review with the non specific close reason "Not suitable for this site - This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline.]

I'd propose using the close reason shown on the post notice here instead, which in this case would be:

> This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers.

Comment: This probably happened because 3 different close reasons were chosen by close voters.

Comment: @M-- A reasonable guess, but all three chose "Not about programming or software development"

Comment: @LW001 Any chance you could link that review task? I'm interested to see what it looks like for users with the close vote privilege (IE 3k+ rep).

Comment: @IanCampbell for perpetuity, it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MADHk.png) (in case it changes after the task is handled).

Comment: @RyanM wait, you can see the individual votes? And then we cannot get them through SEDE even. That's so not fair :(

Comment: @M-- Yep, we can see exactly which close votes and flags were cast, when, and by whom.  It would indeed be nice if SEDE exposed close vote information a bit more, as I don't particularly see any reason why it would raise privacy concerns given that it's more-or-less exposed in various ways through the UI after the question is closed.